# Why am I getting random push notifications from Venmo?

Tags: push-notifications, samsung-galaxy-s-8

I got a Samsung Galaxy S8 not too long ago, and I can't seem to stop push notifications about random Facebook friends making transactions.

First, I *am* logged in, so it's not the random-public-transactions feed. These are all people I am connected to on Facebook.

These are my settings:

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshots (click images for larger variants)</sup>

As you can see, I've turned off all push notifications and social networks. Why am I still getting notifications?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you sure that these notifications are coming because of facebook mobile app only. It may also possible that these notification are coming from some browser. May be you opened facebook within a browser and by mistake you activated the alert notification feature there. Just check it. I wanted to comment on your question because it's not my answer .. it's just a suggestion. But i don't have enough reputation on `android.stackexchange.com` that's why i am giving the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I checked. Venmo's site simply wants me to get the app; I can go no further. As for Facebook, browser notifications appear all off. So I don't think it's through the browser.

Comment: Okay. Then try to uninstall the these apps because after that token will be removed from your device for these particular app. So it'll not come. Do this uninstallation if you remember the credentials for those app.

Comment: If you hold down your finger on the notification for a second, it should show what app the notifications are coming from.

Comment: Any luck? I'm having the same issue. I've confirmed that notifications are coming from the Venmo app. Seems like it's likely an app bug.

Answer (score 1):

When the notification appears up top, swipe the menu down and hold your thumb on the notification for a second or so. There should be 3 options that appear, one being "block notifications."